# How to join repeated values to the same feature using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I new to QGIS, and programming in general.

I'm trying to join a csv file with another file that is already in the project. However, the csv file has repeated values that should allocate to the same feature in the project, which doesn't happen. When I join the values only one of the repeated values appears; the others don't.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: you must use relationship and not a join;
On the Project menu, select Project Properties => relationship

Answer (score 1):

This is more a 'relational database' join than a 'shapefile properties' join...

My suggestion would be to open up the QGIS DB Manager, access your SHP and CSV using the Virtual Layers section, and write some SQL queries to join your data properly.

Then you can add your result back to the map with the 'load as new layer' option.